# How to use next js image optimization when images are served from another microservice in a kubernetes cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, networking, next.js, nextjs-image

I have a react component in my `nextjs` application which uses `next/image`:

```
<Image
    src={`http://backend${image.url}`}
    alt={image.alt}
    width={image.width}
    height={image.height}
    />
```

In line `src={'http://backend${image.url}'}`, `backend` is the name of a kubernetes serivce through which images are available to `nextjs` microservice.

When I deploy it, `nextjs` microservice crashes (with no errors) when rendering the `<Image />` components. (Pages with no `<Image />` get rendered without any problem.)

I don't know the reason but the `pod` restarts the `nexjs` container. I checked `kubectl top pod` to see whether it's because of resource limitations but found no CPU/RAM limitations.

The images are located in a provisioned kubernetes volume. There are two `nginx` microservices which serve the images:

1. One of them serves the images to world, for example web browsers can request images like this: `/media/images/image-1.jpg` (which works fine.)
2. The other one serves the images to the `nextjs` microservice. It includes a kubernetes service named `backend`. For example in `nextjs` container an image can be requested like this:

   `<Image src={'http://backend${image.url}' ... />`

When I turn off image optimization (`unoptimized={true}`) and change the `src` to get the image from the web browser (instead of `nextjs` microservice), everything works fine:

```
<Image
    unoptimized={true}
    src={`${image.url}`}
    alt={image.alt}
    width={image.width}
    height={image.height}
    />
```

I want the image optimization feature. How to handle this problem. Thanks in advance!

***UPDATE***

Is there a way to make `"http://backend/media/image-1.jpg"` and `"/media/image-1.jpg"` equal in `nextjs` microservice? So that `"/media/image-1.jpg"` would get resolved to `"http://backend/media/image-1.jpg"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in next js. It will be ok in the next stable version.

For more information see: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/22644