# Is it possible to access a kubernetes service with a different url?

Tags: kubernetes, networking

When you create a kubernetes service named `myservice`, you can access that service in your pods with urls like this: `http://myservice/media/images/...`.

Is it possible to make urls like `/media/images/...` get resolved to urls like `http://myservice/media/images/...` in a specific kubernetes pod?

For example suppose we have a pod named "podA". Is it possible for containers in "podA" to send GET requests with urls like `/media/images/...` instead of urls like `http://myservice/media/images/...` ?

Comment: Path-only URLs are usually resolved with respect to some base URL and inherit the hostname from that base; how would your "podA" code know what that base URL is?  Can you provide more specific code that demonstrates what you need and why you want to omit the hostname part of the URL?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you David! I'm actually trying to solve this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66424941/how-to-use-next-js-image-optimization-when-images-are-served-from-another-micros

Comment: Hello, I do need to agree with David Maze comment. AFAIK from pure Kubernetes perspective this won't be possible. You would need to have some type of `base_url` provided to your `Pod` which is requesting the content.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the following question:

> Is it possible to make urls like /media/images/... get resolved to urls like http://myservice/media/images/... in a specific kubernetes pod?

**In short, no**.

Take a look on following example:

```
http://awesomeservice/folder/sample.txt
\__/   \_______________/\_______/
 |            |             |
protocol  service name    path to 
                          resource
```

When you try to send a web request for a specific resource (from your Kubernetes `Pod`) you **need** to have a host part. If you tried like: `/media/images/...` you would be telling your OS/software/application that you want a resource from a local filesystem.

You can read more on the topic on how the `Pods` can communicate with each other by following this documentation:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)*

---

As a **workaround** to have an access to your resources on path like `/media/images/...` you could provision the storage solution that would be mounted to your `/media` catalogue. There are multiple ways to achieve that and you would need to refer to the specific solution documentation (it will be different on-premises and in the cloud-managed Kubernetes cluster). As a starting point/baseline you can look on:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Storage: Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)*

---

Giving more visibility to the useful comments made under the question:

> Path-only URLs are usually resolved with respect to some base URL and inherit the hostname from that base; how would your "podA" code know what that base URL is? Can you provide more specific code that demonstrates what you need and why you want to omit the hostname part of the URL? – David Maze

> AFAIK from pure Kubernetes perspective this won't be possible. You would need to have some type of `base_url` provided to your `Pod` which is requesting the content. – Dawid Kruk

---

Additional resources:

- *[Wikipedia.org: Uniform resource identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)*
- *[Wikipedia.org. Wiki: Path (computing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing))*

> **Side note!**
>
> As for:
>
> > Is it possible to make urls like /media/images/... get resolved to urls like http://myservice/media/images/... in a specific kubernetes pod?
>
> If you were thinking about sending the request to a **specific** `Pod` you could look on:
>
> - *[Istio.io: Latest: Docs: Concepts: Traffic management](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/)*